# How to create dynamic url in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to generate a dynamic url like http://domainnamw/maincategory/subcategory/subcategory/

My route rule is

```
Router::connect('/categorydetail/*', array(
     'controller' => 'categorydetail', 
     'action' => 'categorydetail'
));
```

How can this be generated?

Comment: There is no such option in CakePHP (maybe some plugin I am not aware of). I have achieved this by creating an `urls` table with the tree format and made a `UrlBehavior` that generates these unique url's for every category/item added/updated. Afterwards, I route all unrecognized calls to a function that accesses the `urls` table, finds the row by the unique url, reads the model, id and language, and calls the proper function or redirects to a 404 page if the row doesn't exist. My point is, you have to do this your own custom way.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Url helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html) you can do this.
You can produce that link lots of way.here is some example

**1#**

```
$this->Url->build(['controller'=>'maincategory','action'=>'subcategory/subcategory'], true);
```

**2#**

```
$this->Url->build(['controller'=>'maincategory','action'=>'subcategory','subcategory'], true);
```

**Note**: Answer is for cakephp-3.0

For cakephp-2 you can use [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html)

Maybe like this

```
$this->Html->link(
    'Click Here',
    '/maincategory/subcategory/subcategory',   
     array('fullBase' => true)     
);
```

or like this

```
$this->Html->link(
    'Click here',
    array(
        'controller' => 'maincategory',
        'action' => 'subcategory/subcategory',
        'full_base' => true
    )
);
```